# Errors occurred while compiling the file with LuaLaTex

Tags: latex, tex-live

Errors occurred while compiling the file with LuaLaTex.

The tex file is as simple as below:

```
% thesis.tex
\documentclass{fduthesis-en} 

\fdusetup{
  style = {
    bib-backend = bibtex,
    bib-style = numerical,
    bib-resource = {a.bib},
  }
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{hello} 
\section{Welcome to fduthesis!}
hello ，\LaTeX{}! a \cite{test1}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

a.bib looks like this:

```
@article{test1,
author       = {Author One and Author Two and Author Three},   
title        = {TITLE},   
booktitle    = {Book Title},   
journal      = {Journal Title},   
volume       = {2},   
number       = {3},   
address      = {Address}, 
}
```

Error message is shown as below:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xunicode-addon.sty:87: Missing } inserted. [\AtEndUTFCommand { \group_end:]
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xunicode-addon.sty:87: Extra \endgroup. [\AtEndUTFCommand { \group_end:]
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xunicode-addon.sty:87: Too many }'s. [\AtEndUTFCommand { \group_end: }]
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/ctexbook.cls:14: Argument of \use_none:n has an extra }. [hello ，\LaTeX{}! a \cite{test1}]
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/ctexbook.cls:14: Paragraph ended before \use_none:n was complete. [hello ，\LaTeX{}! a \cite{test1}]
/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/ctexbook.cls:14: Missing \endcsname inserted. [hello ，\LaTeX{}! a \cite{test1}]
```

Comment: Why don't you remove an unnecessary comma from`address = {Address},` of your bib file? The last line of each bib item should be ended without a comma.